# Could someone help me avoid using eval()?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have this code:

```
  var Monday = scheduledb({
      "monday": true
  }).count();
  var Tuesday = scheduledb({
      "tuesday": true
  }).count();
  var Wednesday = scheduledb({
      "wednesday": true
  }).count();
  var Thursday = scheduledb({
      "thursday": true
  }).count();
  var Friday = scheduledb({
      "friday": true
  }).count();
  $$(".day-selector").each(function (index) {
      $$(this).text(eval($$(this).attr("id")) + " classes");
  });
```

What I'm trying to do is to use the value I get from the id attribute of an element and do a database lookup for it. But the `.attr()` returns a string, which I can't get a variable value from. How can I do this without using eval()?

Comment: What does the code for Monday until Friday have to do with this question? Please provide some sample data of what would be the raw `id` value. Also: is `$$` jQuery?

Comment: Eval is used when you have code in string. There is no need for eval in your code. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: @trincot An example of what `id` would be is `Monday` so I wanted to use that value to reference a variable. $$ is Framework 7 DOM manipulation library, like jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a better model so you do not need to use eval

```
var days = {
 Monday : scheduledb({"monday": true}).count(),
 Tuesday : scheduledb({"tuesday": true}).count(), 
 ...
};
```

than bracket notation:

```
$$( this ).text(days[$$( this ).attr("id")])
```

or just forgo the lookup

```
var obj = {};
obj[$$( this ).attr("id").toLowerCase()] = true;
$$( this ).text( scheduledb(obj).count() )
```

Comment: Making the lookups an object fixed it, thanks!